# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cycle' of undefined

Tags: plugins, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cycle' of undefined
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js?ver=5.2.1:473)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.Plugin [as carousel] (bootstrap.js?ver=5.2.1:464)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js?ver=5.2.1:520)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at bootstrap.js?ver=5.2.1:518
at dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I have updated the jQuery verion to above 1.9.1 and below 3 after an error has shown to update bootstrap version not supported by it. But after that, this is the error

Comment: Edit: The issue can be solved by using Core JS Bootstrap version which is also greater than 1.9.1 and less than 3.

Comment: So, you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes, it's working now.